# VBA Index Match with a loop with two conditions

Tags: excel, vba, loops, indexing, match

I hope that someone could help me with an index match formula that is made using a loop and storing the results data on the column.

**Let's say that my data is following to make it simple:**
We have an employee column and a salary column. I want to find all the salary options for HR employees.
**I would like to store automatically all the results found on the column J (Researched input is in column I).** And I want to finish the loop after not finding any new values.

Here is the data:

[image]

**My initial code is down below without a loop to go down on the range:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value <> ""
        Set oCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9))
        If Not oCell Is Nothing Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10) = oCell.Offset(0, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You've tagged this with VBA... can you [edit] the question with the code you're trying?

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from two main things:

- The `.Find` range you are searching is the ***entire*** column A, which is then set to a `.Range` object (oCell). However, from my VBA understanding the `.Find` method cannot apply the cell address of each instance of the string/search parameter you are looking for. It will ***only*** apply the cell address of the **first** one it finds. To set a **.Range** object of non-contiguous rows you could use **UNION** function.
- The `.Find(What:= ...` is set to a dynamic range which moves down column I as the loop continues. This means it will ***never*** find a match because it is searching the preceding column.

Here is a suggested solution, which hopefully you can adapt to your real world data:

```
Option Explicit
'
Sub test()
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1

    Do While Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
        ' Included as a sense check when stepping through your code to confirm loop is on correct cell
        'Debug.Print Cells(i, 2).Address
        'Debug.Print Cells(i, 2).Value
        'Debug.Print "NEXT"
        Set oCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10").Find(What:="HR")
        If Not oCell Is Nothing Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = oCell.Offset(0, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer, but I think that the problem with a moving range to find all the elements is not solved...  I tried to create a moving range using variables  "Set oCell = Worksheets("R&A").Range("A" & x & ":A" & y).Find(What:=Worksheets("Main Menu").Cells(i, 9)) ", but I have no idea how to loop it to get all the results one by one. I think that I need to use address of the previous cell that was found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wb as Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws as Excel.Worksheet

    i = 2   ' we don't need the header
    set wb = ActiveWorkBook
    set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")  ' or wb.Sheets(1)

    Do While ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        If ws.Cells(i,1) = "HR" then
            ws.Cells(i, 3) = ws.Cells(i,2)
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Tested and found working